# Is the "Internet background noise" a real danger or a negligible parasite?

Tags: firewall, ddos, network-traffic, network-security

I recently setup a network traffic filter (a firewall) on my 'personal' VPS in such a way that it records some informations on incoming unwanted packages as the source IP address and the destination port number. To simplify, every unrecognised TCP/UDP packets knocking at the door of my server is logged into a file.
After 7 days, this filter dropped out thousands of different unauthorized requested, 8920 different sources, 20489 packets in total.

[image]

```
1.203.193.140 : CHINANET Beijing Province Network, China
1.20.241.112  : TOT Public Company Limited, Thailand
1.188.96.44   : China Unicom Heilongjiang province network, China
1.180.72.186  : CHINANET NeiMengGu province network, Chine
1.171.181.193 : Data Communication Business Group, Taiwan
1.164.24.255  : Data Communication Business Group, Taiwan
```

- Is it dangerous or just a harmless traffic noise ?
- Where all this traffic is coming from and where is it supposed to go ?
- What is the proportion of this traffic on the internet (quantity and size) ?

Answer (score 1):

This should mostly be automated network security scans (with potential malicious intent). Sadly this is normal but should not be a security problem as long as you have basic measures in place (no default passwords, brute-force prevention, up to date software).

Something that I've seen when analyzing incoming web-traffic was, that most of it was related to vulnerabilities with router/access-point software. You can easily separate this traffic by the used port numbers (or install a sandbox/honeybot such as [Conpot (SCADA)](http://conpot.org/) to further analyze the incoming traffic.